# angularjs directives and resource concepts

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been playing around with angularjs and calls to rest services to show specific sets of data, however I am struggling with some concepts around custom directives and resources.

At the moment I have a custom directive that loads a list of comments in a system. The list of comments is a custom directive that loads the list through a resource call and shows the list. This is working fine in Page A.

In page B, I show a single user through a url. e.g. site.com/user/3 - this is loaded as a REST resource as the model of the page. This also works fine.

What I am trying to achieve is to put the comments directive in the users page so that it displays a list of comments just by that user. I am working on the assumption that I can somehow take the user and somehow pass it through to the directive as a filter on the comments.

This is approach does not appear to be working. As far as I can tell, the directive is being applied before the promise of the user has been completed, so I end with the unfiltered comments.

In short, how can I get my directive to load the filtered comments after the load of the user data is completed?

Please note I am talking users and comments to give people an idea of what I trying to do. The actual data is more domain-specific, but the data relationships are the same. I also have deliberately not posted the code because I'm trying to understand the correct approach I should be taking, not a specific code issue.

Comment: Your question here is full of misunderstandings (or perhaps just misused terminology), and would probably be better handled in a discussion.  we can use the [AngularJs](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63378/angularjs) room if you like....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really in favour of hard and fast rules but, in my opinion:

- directives are really for DOM manipulation + presentation, preferably as autonomous, reusable components. In your example your directive should be concerned purely with the UI of displaying a list of comments.
- Interaction with the server, filtering of comments, etc. should be managed by a service which will be a dependency of your directive. So in your example you would have a method in the service: getUserComments = function(userID) which retrieves the comments for that user. The directive takes that data and updates its section of the DOM.

It would look like:

```
angular.service('CommentService',
    function($http, $q){

        this.getUserComments = function(userID){

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get('site.com/user/' + userID).
                success(function(comments) {

                   deferred.resolve(comments)

                }).
                error(function(data, status) {

                   deferred.reject(status);

                });

            return deferred.promise;
        };

    }
); // End CommentService

angular.directive('commentList',
   function(CommentService){

      return {
         restrict : 'EA',
         template : '<ul><li ng-repeat="comment in comments">{{comment.text}}</li></ul>',
         scope : true,
         replace : true,
         link : function(scope, elem, attrs){

             // get User ID from somewhere
             var userID = 3;
             CommentService.getUserComments(userID).then(
                 function(comments){
                    scope.comments = comments;
                 }
             );

         }  
      }
   }
);
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thanks also to Claies who provided me with some insight into correcting my approach in a chat session. I used this method by yellowmelon and it works a treat/.